# Non-literal bringing of something to somewhere

Tags: usage, word-usage

I understand that to bring an object to somewhere would roughly translate to

> ～にXを持って来て

I've used this sentence structure for physical objects on numerous occasions, and have wondered if it would still be correct to use the same structure when you are not *literally* requesting something to be brought over.

For example, assuming the UK does not celebrate Halloween (Not quite sure if they do), would it be grammatically correct to say

> イギリスにハロウィーンを持って来てくれ！

or assuming a product (for example Pepsi) is not available in some region

> ～にペプシを持って来てくれ！

or perhaps even to bring an idea such as democracy?

> ～に民主主義を持って来てください

In the first and last example, nothing is requested to be *physically* brought over, only requested to be *introduced*. In the second, while there in a physical item involved, you're still not literally requesting a can of Pepsi to be brought to said region.

Would it still be the right way to say it?

Comment: You missed the っ in 持って. I tried to edit your question but it says my edit is too small :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only in highly informal speech, all of your examples can be expressed with 「持{も}ってくる」, but in formal speech, it would look and sound far better if you used other words.

(By the way, the phrase in question is 「持ってくる」 and not 「持てくる」.  The latter makes little sense.)

Halloween to Country A:

> 「[Country A] + **に** + ハロウィーン + **を** + 紹介{しょうかい}する」 ("to introduce") or
>
> 「[Country A] + **に** + ハロウィーン + **を** + 広{ひろ}める」 ("to spread")

A new product to a place:

> 「[Place] + **で** + ペプシ + **を** + 売{う}り出{だ}す」 "to start selling" or
>
> 「[Place] + **に** + ペプシ + **を** + 紹介する」 ("to introduce")

Democracy to a place:

> 「[Place] + **に** + 民主主義｛みんしゅしゅぎ｝ + **を** + 導入｛どうにゅう｝する」

「導入する」 means "***to introduce a new system***".  A good word to add to your vocab.

Comment: 質問文の「持って」を何も考えず修正した後に、回答で指摘されていることに気づきました。私のせいで質問と回答内容に齟齬が生じたのは申し訳ないのですが該当部分更新するなり何なりしていただければ幸いです。